# PMD maven plugin not working for jdk 1.7

Tags: maven, pmd

When I run mvn pmd:check with JAVA_HOME set to jdk 1.8, this runs smoothly. When I switch the jdk to 1.7 I get following exception.
PMD support 1.7, so not sure why I am getting this error.

Caused by: org.apache.maven.plugin.PluginContainerException: An API incompatibility was encountered while executing org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-pmd-plugin:3.8:pmd: java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError:  : Unsupported major.minor version 52.0

Anybody faced the same issue?

Answer (score 1):

52.0 is Java 8. This meant that I was somehow trying to run Java 8 code in a Java 7 VM. Eventhough my jdk and JAVA_HOME was set to 7.
The pmd plugin I was using was version 3.8 , which seems to support jdk 8+.
I downgraded my maven-pmd-plugin to 3.7. And the exception went away.

Answer (score 0):

That's weird. PMD is still working with JDK7 - as is maven. JDK8 is only required, if you want to analyze Salesforce.com Apex code.

Would you mind running mvn with the `-e` or `-X` option, to see which class is for java8? You should get a stacktrace then. It might be caused by a dependency.

Also: Which version of maven are you using?

Comment: I am using maven 3.3.9.  When I downgraded my pmd plugin to 3.7, the exception went away.